# Why don't controllers added to the React template for Asp.Net work?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I built the React template with `dotnet new react -o my-new-app`
Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");;

app.Run();
```

The controller that I added.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace my_new_app.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DifferentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<DifferentController> _logger;

    public DifferentController(ILogger<DifferentController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(_ => "hello world")
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

My front-end request:

```
async populateWeatherData() {
    const differentResponse = await fetch('different');
    const differentData = await differentResponse.text();
    const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
  }
```

`differentData` will always print out as the index.html. Why is it doing this? I understand that the index.html is the fallback; I understand that the server is trying to serve the front-end assets and be the api at the same time, but why would `fetch` work for `weatherdata` and not `different`? I have tried possible combination of mapcontrollers, mapendpoints, mapdefaultcontrollerroute, addcontrollerswithviews, etc. that I could find online, so I feel that there is something fundamental I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The API is not the same port as the SPA, so whenever I was trying to fetch data the server was sending the only thing that it could. Now, when I add `different` to the context in setupProxy.js like so...

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware'); const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :   env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:37776';

const context =  [   "/weatherforecast",   "/different", ];

module.exports = function(app) {   const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }   });

  app.use(appProxy); };
```

...the fetch returns the correct data.

I confirmed by issuing a get request on a different port.